# Laravel storage exists method is not working for sub folders

Tags: php, laravel

I have to use laravel 7 in my project. i want to check file is exists under multiple sub folders But exists method not working for sub folders. Below is my code.

```
$name  = https://selvamani-s3.amazonaws.com/ServiceReport/service_report_1657541906.pdf

$basename = basename($name);
if ($remoteStorage->exists('/ServiceReport/' . $basename)) {
     echo "File Exists";
}else{
     echo "File Not Exists";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options to check if file exists or not.
Using Using File System:

```
public function checkFile(Request $request){

$path = public_path('upload/file.png');

$isExists = File::exists($path);

dd($isExists);
}
```

Or you can using Storage System[Have a look](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem):

```
 $isExists = Storage::exists('upload/file.png');

dd($isExists);
```